# How understand if debug card not works properly?

Tags: debugging

I want to find some chips datasheet of some computer POST Test Main Board Diagnostic Analyzer Card like this.

[image]

Can you provide me some examplex, please ?
I want to understand which circuits works inside because.. how understand if debug card is broken ?
In this case.. I need to debug a debugger

Comment: Datasheets, examples, how-to's... So what are you asking about, again?

Comment: I change title How understand if debug card not works properly?

Comment: It's less than US$5 on eBay _including shipping_. Why would you bother trying to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The Power On Self-Test (POST) is actually firmware that resides in the BIOS ROM. The only thing the board does is provide some standardized I/O that the firmware can use to show its results when the main system display is not (yet known to be) working.

The card just contains some hardware registers that control the various LEDs and the buzzer that you see. This one may have a small microcontroller on it for the 7-segment display. It also has some status lights for the system power buses and a few key bus signals.

There really isn't much point to repairing a broken board; just get a new one.